# Difference between get() and first() method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am a fresher in laravel .I am trying to learn Eloquent ORM process in laravel. I read there documentation but I am not getting the difference between get() and first() method.

```
$flight =Flight::where('active', 1)->first();


$flight =Flight::where('active', 1)->get();
```

can someone explain this things. Thanks in advance

Comment: `get()` returns a collection object containing `Flight` models for all records that match the WHERE condition; `first()` returns a `Flight` model object of just one (the first) match for the WHERE clause